# Is it possible to run a ZF2 application on Resin with Quercus?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, resin, quercus

I am attempting to set up a very basic Zend Framework 2 application to run on
Resin using Quercus as a proof of concept. I'm running into some issues, and I
haven't been able to find any open source examples of a ZF2 application running
on Resin.

I've managed to get PHP working, but I am seeing errors about functionality
normally included by the PHP SPL extension when trying to load my Zend
application. It appears that SPL is not fully implemented by Quercus, so
hopefully there's a work-around I can use if that is the case.

The first error I saw was about a missing function: `spl_object_hash`. I wrote
a placeholder for this method to get around the error for now (it's pretty
terrible, I know):

```
if (!function_exists('spl_object_hash')) {
    function spl_object_hash() {
        usleep(1);
        return md5(microtime());
    }
}
```

The next two errors were about the missing classes: `SplPriorityQueue` and
`SplStack`. I wrote some placeholders for those as well, going by the
documentation here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.spl.php. These
placeholder classes are basically just wrappers for an array.

The error I'm running into now is:

> .../library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:456: Fatal Error: Uncaught exception of type 'Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException' with message 'Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for Application Location[.../library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:456]'

I'm not really sure where to go from here.

For reference, I'm using:

- http://www.caucho.com/download/debian/dists/precise/universe/binary-amd64/resin_4.0.38-amd64.deb
- https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/tree/2f60f8af002e6b7afc9f47a5e79e038e0baf5e3a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied this question to the Caucho Quercus Google Group, and I received [this response](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/caucho-quercus/0fLHPOd2r4M/s2mwAX2ZSjsJ).

It appears that at this time, it is not possible to run a Zend Framework 2 application using Resin and Quercus.

The missing function `spl_object_hash` has been implemented for the upcoming 4.0.39 release<sup>†</sup>.

Additionally, Nam Nguyen of Caucho submitted the following bug reports on my behalf:

- [0005666: implement SplPriorityQueue and SplStack](http://bugs.caucho.com/view.php?id=5666)
- [0005667: Zend Framework 2 demo application not working](http://bugs.caucho.com/view.php?id=5667)

<sub>† http://bugs.caucho.com/view.php?id=5623</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Resin is a web server designed for running Java Applications. ZF2 is using PHP + some PHP extensions. Quercus implementation of PHP may not support those extensions. You probably need a web server with Apache or Nginx instead.

Comment: Indeed, Quercus does not support the entirety of the SPL extension (see my update above). According to Nam Nguyen of Caucho, it's about 80% complete.